# Subset of $C^2[0,1]$ dense in $C^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Given that $C^2[0,1]$:= {continuous functions on $[0,1]$ : $d(x(t),y(t))=(\int_0^1{|x(t)-y(t)|^2}dt)^{1/2})$},

Can someone help me in proving that the set continuous functions on $[0,1]$

such that $f(0)=f(1)$ is dense in $C^2[0,1]$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Fix $\delta >0$. You need to show that for each $f \in C^2[0,1]$, there is a function $g$ with $g(0)=g(1)$ such that $\|g-f\|<\delta$.

Use the fact that continuous functions on compact intervals are bounded. Cut off your function $f$ at both ends sufficiently close that you won't affect the norm much, and then stitch it back up linearly so that the endpoints are equal (or, just as easily, both equal to zero, which suffices to prove your result).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. However, can you explain in more detail as I do not quite comprehend the part on the "stitching"? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Say $f$ is bounded by $N$. Define $g$ to be linear on $[0,\varepsilon/N]$, equal to $f$ on $[\varepsilon/N,1-\varepsilon/N]$, linear on $[1-\varepsilon/N,1]$. If you think about this for a while, you will see that you can choose the linear bits such that $g(0)=g(1)=0$, but so that $g$ remains continuous. Now try and estimate how badly doing this has affected the norm (try and bound $\|f-g\|$).

Comment: Hey thanks alot for the help.:)